# Proper way to get error message and code from exception

Tags: java

I have a simple try catch method that returns an exception as String

```
public class Program {
    try {
        someFunction()
    } catch (Exception e){
        // i need to get the code and message as strings
    }
}
```

these are some examples of the exceptions I can get:

```
You have got the error. [ErrorCode: 400 XYZ]
You have got the error. [ErrorCode: 404 XYZ]
You got error which has no errorCode
```

and these are the error codes I want for each of these exceptions:

```
INVALID_TEMPLATE
REQUEST_REJECTED
NO_ERROR_CODE
```

I tried a few things and this is what I came up with

```java
public class Program {
  try {

    someFunction(x);

  } catch (Exception e) {

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    String message = sw.toString();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*:\\s+(.*)\\s+\\[ErrorCode: (\\d+)").matcher(message);
    if (m.find()) {
      String errorMessage = m.group(1); // You have got the error.
      String errorCode = m.group(2); // 400
      // Here I want to fetch the error Category based on the errorCode
      String errorCategory = XYZ.errorCategory(errorCode);

      `//Based on`
      the errorCode, errorCategory of INVALID_TEMPLATE which is an enum must be returned
      SomeOtherFunc(errorCategory, errorMessage);

    }

  }

  public class XYZ {

    private static final Map < String, String > errorMap = new HashMap < > ();

    public void populateErrorMap() {
      errorMap.put("400", INVALID_TEMPLATE(400, 400));
      errorMap.put("404", REQUEST_REJECTED(404, 404));

    }

  }

  public static String errorCategory(String errorCode) {
    return errorMap.get(errorCode);
  }
```

Is this optimal or is there a better solution?
Also this is still unable to handle the exception in case there is no error code 
(should return NO_ERROR_CODE).
How can I archive that?

Comment: Are those exceptions defined by you? If they are you can make a custom base exception with all the fields you need, catch them instead of `Exception` and expose those fields instead of trying to parse the message.

Comment: those exception are not defined by me. I want to read the error Code, if it comes, and then send to 3rd party by a defined error Category which i put in the value pair of HashMap. If the error Code doesn't come, some other way to read the message and then categorize it and then again send to 3rd party. What can be a good design to do it?

Comment: Please format your code so that people can read it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your issue properly
If you want to transform your exception code to a custom category this looks shorter:

```
public class Program {
    Map<Integer, String> errorMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    errorMap.put(400, "INVALID_TEMPLATE");
    errorMap.put(404, "REQUEST_REJECTED");
    try {
        someFunction (x) ;
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        SomeOtherFunction(errorMap.get(e.getStatusCode()),errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could add multiple catches for each exception type if you want to call different functions.

```
try {
    someFunction (x) ;
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    // do this if exception 1
    callThisFunction1()
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
    // do this if exception 2
    callThisFunction2()
} catch(ExceptionType3 | Exceptiontype4 ex) {
   // do this if exception 3 or 4
    callThisFunction3()
}
```

Also please try to write down your questions better, like give it a proper order.

```
1)your input
2)your desired output
3)your code
4)the issue
```

Thank you...

Comment: I have now frame the question, Is it clearer now ?

I basically need to call the function which calls based on error Code if there is and return me error Category from another function . If there is no error Code coming in exception, I need to read the message contents and then provide a separate error category to it.

Comment: @user13734449 Not really... the order is still all over the place, the code is not formatted and I have no idea if your examples are some scenarios that actually appeared or a simple what if. If you want to ask for help please consider the reader's point of view.

Comment: @user13734449 I have not tested my code but is there a reason you cannot use ```e.getStatusCode()```? And is there a reason you have a whole class just for your map? Is there really a scenario in which there is no status code in the exception?

Comment: @user13734449 And if your question is simply about how to improve your design you probably do not want to post it here, since you are not actually having an issue with your current code.

Comment: In actual, exception e instance doesn't have Status Code. I am filtering it with a matcher and then picking as String. so i have to fetch the value in String as error code and then find the eror Category once it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In real life there are two audiences:

- the log handler with a configurable log level (ERROR) and logging (in English) with much info;
- the end user with an localized translated message, also with parameters.

The first property is that you probably want a message as format `String` with `Object...` parameters. Probably should use `MessageFormat`.

Sensible would be to support typed parameters.

```
/** Type-checkable Message Definition. */
public record MessageDef(String format, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
    public void checkFormat() {
        ... check actual parameters with parameterTypes.length
    }
    public void checkUsage(Object[] args) {
        ... check parameter types
    }
}
```

One could make an enum for the error categories. However enums are more suitable for closed domains with a fixed set of values. Extending values in future means that you have created a needless common bottleneck for source version control and so on.
An error is more like an *open* domain. However if you number them with error codes, an enum gives a nice overview.

The only advantage of error codes is the internationalisation. An Hungarian error message can be easily retrieved.

Then, if you rethrow check exceptions as RuntimeException, like IllegalArgumentException or you own custom ones, you might not want parallel classes: run-time exceptions and categories.

All-in-all I would advise an enum:

```
public enum MessageType {
    INVALID_TEMPLATE(400, Level.ERROR,
        new MessageDef("You have got the error in {0}.", String.class)),
    ...
    REQUEST_REJECTED(200, Level.INFO,
        new MessageDef("Done."));

    public final int code;
    public final Level level;
    public final MessageDef def;

    MessageType(int code, Level level, MessageDef def) {
        this.code = code;
        this.level = level;
        this.def = def;
    }
}
```

One small remark: such little discussion points in the beginning of a project sometimes might be better postponed to a fast refactoring after having written sufficient code. Here an enum might not fit, you might have much re-throwing of exceptions. A premature decision is not needed. And might hamper fast productivity.
Especially as you probably need not mark the code places, you most likely call the same show-error dialog.